# iOS: user authentication via oAuth

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth

**In a nut shell,** I have an iOS app which will act as a GUI for managing user data. Data is exclusive to its user so some secure method of authorisation is required.
I'll be making use of `HTTPS` to keep everything secret but I wish to minimise the use of `username:password` in session.

From research I have this tutorial which puts everything nicely: http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/2010/06/01/oauth2-for-iphone-and-ipad-applications/

My uncertainty comes with the initiation where we require,  "`1.Your client's unique ID, redirect URI and secret token`".

The tutorial states that: `"If possible, you should try and obtain the end-user and token URIs at runtime rather than hardcoding them into your application. This can be typically done by making an unauthorised request to a secure URI and obtaining them from the WWW-Authenticate header in the returned 401 response"`
I understand the first part of that statement, but the method as explained in the second half isn't what I expected and kinda seems alittle insecure?

in my head, I imagined something closer to hashing the `username:password` combination, sending that across during the app login stage, on confirmation from server obtaining the returned secret key (resulting in the `username:password` only being sent down the wire once)

What is the best way to obtain the redirect URI, and secret token??

Comment: This really depends on the server you're communicating with. Do you still have to build the server-side user management and authentication? Normally, when writing an iOS app, you just follow the server's API instructions. Simple authentication using a login with username:password over HTTPS works well, if the server returns you a login token, you just pass that in subsequent requests. No need to do anything with OAuth2 unless you're accessing a service that requires it.

Comment: yes I do have to (continue building it anyway). I think your right, I remember asking how best todo the entire method as described in the question and someone pointed me to oAuth, but I've only found it good for integrating services and a lot of overkill for what I require. I had an initial plan to have a homebrew service like the one you've described so I think i'll stick with that. thanks very mcuh

Comment: What you need to do is make sure you expire the login token within a decent time frame, that way they can't be re-used/abused. And then, if the app requests a resource with the expired token, your server responds with a special 'token expired' error (403 unauthorised) and your app automatically refreshes it by logging in again (without user interaction, save the username and password).

Comment: that was the idea I had in mind. I think with security, the term 'don't reinvent the wheel' got me a little unsure on my own plan.
if you wanted to, you welcome to summarize your comments into an answer & i'll accept it